# How to add a package to a custom laravel package?

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm building a custom Laravel package which requires the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` package. Below is my composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "lomse/awesomePackage",
  "description": "this an awesome package",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Selom",
      "email": "awesome@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Lomse\\AwesomePackage\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the content of my `AwesomeProvider.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Lomse\AwesomePackage;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AwesomeProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(){
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Awesome::class, function ($app) {
            return new Awesome(new Client); //Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
        });
    }
}
```

I keep getting `Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `composer update` after editing composer.json?

Comment: Yes I did. I even deleted the vendor folder and the composer.lock file and run composer dump-autoload afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this turns out to be quite simple. I highlighted the steps to take in order to solve this. Hope this helps anyone who is having the same issue.

1. I had to push my code to a repo `lomse/awesome-package` on Github
2. then specified `preferred-install` as `dist` in the `./lomse/awesome-package/package.json` config property`:

   "config": {
       "preferred-install": "dist"
   }

The full code is

```
{
  "name": "lomse/awesome-package",
  "description": "this an awesome package",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Selom",
      "email": "awesome@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Lomse\\AwesomePackage\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

In the root `package.json`, specify the repository of your package as follow:

```
"repositories": [
   {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:lomse/awesome-package.git"
   }
]
```

Also add your package repo to the package.json `require` property as shown below:

```
"lomse/awesome-package": "dev-master"
```

From your root directory, run the code below to update your dependencies. This will clone the `lomse/awesome-package` repo into your vendor folder and install any other dependencies required by your package:

```
composer update -vvv
```

`-vvv` is for debugging purposes

[image]

[image]